# How can I find out if a range Index exists?

Tags: marklogic

With an XPath `a/b/c`, is there any way to find out whether or not there is an element range index on element `c`?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand the question either, but there are a couple of ways to find out if a range index exists.

You can try to construct a range index reference using [https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-reference](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts%3aelement-reference) or [https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:path-reference](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts%3apath-reference) for example. The reference constructor will throw an error if the range index does not exist, and you could test for that error. For example:

```
try { cts:element-reference(xs:QName('DNE')) }
catch($ex) {
  if (not($ex/error:code = 'XDMP-ELEMRIDXNOTFOUND')) then xdmp:rethrow()
  else xdmp:log(text { 'No element range index on DNE!' }) }
```

The other approach is to use the admin API: [https://docs.marklogic.com/admin:database-get-range-element-indexes](https://docs.marklogic.com/admin%3adatabase-get-range-element-indexes) and its associated functions. You might expect this to be more efficient than try-catch on an element reference, but it will probably be slower. However the admin API allows testing of arbitrary database configurations fairly easily.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a “reverse” XPath selection, the XPath analog to [reverse query](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:reverse-query). Given a set of paths, which matches a particular node? For element range indexes, it’s pretty straight forward to match against local name, namespace, and type. Matching against paths or fields are more complex.

One idea: Could path matching be accomplished by setting up a dynamic XSLT stylesheet with an `xsl:template match="path"` for each path and transforming the node’s parent document? Is there an easier way?

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer to your question is: if you didn't configure an element range index, then you don't have one. You can look in your database configuration to see whether you created an element range index or a path index that ends with the element you care about.

I suspect you may be asking a different question, but I'm not sure what it is. Why do you want to know?